# Exactly how much time does Cooper spend on Miller's planet?

Tags: interstellar

In the movie *Interstellar*, Cooper & the crew landed on Miller's planet & they got hit a by a wave. After that Dr. Brand states that it cost us decades, & to be precise 23 years. So, in calculation, exactly how much time do they spend on Miller's planet including descent, landing, wave hitting, engines flooding & back to Endurance?
P.S. :- Like director could have represented or mentioned that they spent plenty of time on Millers planet.

Comment: Wait, you want time from their perspective, or Endurance's? The first isn't known, second you mention yourself.

Comment: @Mithoron I'm sorry. My mistake. I want to know from "their" perspective. On the Miller planet, exactly how much time did they spend? Director didn't specify that in the entire movie.

Comment: @Suhail - they spent three hours on the planet.. As described in my answer..

Answer (score 2):

We don't know exactly how much time each individual action took. But we can try to come up with a reasonable estimation.

We can start by looking at how much time they were away from the Endurance:

Cooper says after they've landed that one hour on the surface of the planet would be equal to 7 years on Earth.

When the crew get back to the Endurance Romilly says that he's waited for

> "Twenty-three years, four months, eight days".

With this we can calculate that the crew spent a little over 3 hours on the surface of Miller's planet.

When the first wave hits CASE says they have 45 minutes to an hour to let the water drain from the engines.

Just before the second wave hits them, Cooper asks CASE how much longer they have to wait for the engines. CASE replies with "a minute or two".

So let's assume best case scenario: since the first wave and the second 43 minutes have passed. Including their first few minutes walking around I would say they have been on the surface of the planet in between 45 minutes, and 50 minutes.

Including some time taken for the initial landing and then the dramatic take off sequence, I would put the whole ordeal at a little over an hour.

We don't know how long it took for them to go from the Endurance to the surface of the planet and vice versa, so I'm going to assume it took around an hour both ways just to match up with the earlier calculation.

With all that, give or take a few minutes, we have our 3 hours.

Comment: It's much trickier than that to calculate; obviously they don't suddenly jump to the planet's time rate the instant they separate from *Endurance*; their time rate would change continuously (as in a continuous function, and probably a uniformly continuous one at that) from ship time to planet time.  It's probably not a linear function either, it's a gravity-related phenomenon, so it would be quadratic...

Comment: @DavidW I agree 100%. I would love to find out an exact answer, but until then an estimation will have to do

Comment: Note:  Of everything in this movie, including the "solid foam" planet, the useless expedition to Miller's planet bugged me most.  The time differential _must_ be known, since you can measure the bitrate from Miller's beacon, which has transmitted information about surface conditions.  So wait 10 minutes (of planet time) - a little over a year for Endurance, and plenty of time to visit the other worlds - for an actual _report_ before going.  What's the freaking hurry?!

Comment: This answer is copied from the another question like this but I've edited my question & I want to know why director didn't showed that they've spent more than they represented in the movie. Director didn't justify this scene anywhere in the movie.

Comment: @Suhail - this answer I wrote out myself and did not copy anything apart from what was said by Romilly. And the director didn't show all that time they spent on the planet because that would make for an incredibly boring movie